# Can't use "?" in friendly url

Tags: url, modx

How allow question mark in friendly url? If I i use "?" in friendly url? Using question mark results 503 eroor.

Talk about MODx Revo CMF. Maybe need modify .htacces rule, but how? For example this:

```
# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &wctx=mgr(\S+)source=\s+ [NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

no - you can't, a "?" denotes the beginning of a query string.